# angular 2 google maps error RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: angular, maps

Trying to connect google maps to my app and have that error:

> Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>
> Your site URL to be authorized

What i do ?

I create api key and copy it in my app. I add google APIs to it and my ip to HTPP credentials like this:

```
*.localhost:4200/*

http://localhost/

*.localhost:4200/

*.localhost:4200/

localhost:4200/*
```

And many other.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem and I have solved it by leaving apiKey blank and your code should be like this

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: ''
    })
```

And make sure to enable google maps API for your project.